# Do we have binary dividers circuit in CISC computers?

Tags: circuit-design, multiplier

Just like we have binary multipler circuit in cisc computer so do we have binary divider circuit in cisc computer? Or it is just like we use subtractor multiple time instead of having a real divider circuit? (Just like risc don't have multiplier circuit so it use adders circuit instead of multiplier circuit).

Comment: Add more context about what you are trying to do.  There are processors that have a hardware multiply divide unit but  divide is much less common.  Also even without a multiply function there are better ways to multiply than just repeated addition.  Think 'long multiplication' but in binary.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: *Hell no downvoters* Easy: use concise (possibly short) sentences with punctuation (there is **no** punctuation in your question). Dividers, divide what and how? *I still want answer* Then write a decent and clear question. Also "just wanting something" doesn't really help here. You get as much back as you put in. Well formulated questions have more chance of receiving a proper answer.

Comment: Google "Booth's algorithm" which is the standard (but not only and not fastest possible) method for multiplication and division.

Comment: Have a look at Booths Algorithm.

Comment: Multiplication and division for RISC are pseudo instructions. It's essentially recursive addition and subtraction respectively along with shifting and rotation in bits.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractor

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier

Comment: I can find wikipedia documents about adder, subtractor and multiplier but i don't really can find document about a divider circuit on wikipedia so i think there is no real divider circuit we just use a lot of subtractor circuit like risc dont't have multipliers so it use adders ciruit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are arithmetic binary multipliers and then there are clock frequency multipliers.

I'll discuss some of it only, you decide what you want.

For how arithmetic multipliers and dividers work, read [here](http://www.asic-world.com/digital/arithmetic4.html)

Frequency multipliers work in several ways;

1) by using a **PLL** to divide down to the mixer frequency. **So the multiplier is actually a divider.** (binary, BCD or fraction N types)
2) by using delay gates with cascaded stages and a faster XOR gate to detect the transitions. (used by 700MHz RISC CPU's)
3) diode x2 RF multiplier.
4) harmonic pulse injected BP tuned resonator

CISC processors are more efficient at utilizing memory bandwidth with variable length and more complex instructions, so **a CISC like the 8086 but they use a PLL to multiply the FSB clock using binary dividers**

So it is an Apples and Oranges question.

A RISC may use an XOR gate delay multiplier for simplicity, while an Intel or AMD CISC uses a divider to PLL a faster internal VCO clock.

Comment: Because the question is unclear this answer is about frequency division. That might not be what you tried to ask. Tony made an assumption because the question is unclear.

Comment: His answer was right while he made an assumptions

Answer (score 4):

You can build binary [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) logic easily, but it is generally frequency limited as the signals need to propagate through the entire circuit before the result is available, and each step is dependent on the previous.

The addition steps in multiplications can be parallelized, so you can trade off logic complexity for faster execution, but this cannot be done for division, so it is less common to have dedicated logic for a full divider, especially in microprocessors. There might be a state machine that can perform one shift/compare/subtract per cycle, giving you a result for a 32 bit divisor after 32 cycles.

Large CPUs have full dividers because they can afford the logic gates, and instructions with variable execution time would increase the complexity of instruction scheduling.